# HTML emails sent through rails arrive as attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, postfix-mta, mailer

Following problem: Whenever I try to sent a HTML-email through rails, it arrives at my googlemail-adress as an empty email with the content as an attachment.

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Setup as follows:

```
/app/mailers/testmail.rb
class Testmail < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "our_adress@our.router"
  default_url_options[:host] = '10.10.8.1'

  def email
    subject 'Willkommen!'
    recipients 'me@googlemail.com'
    from 'our_adress@our.router'
    sent_on Time.now
  end
end

/app/views/testmail/email.html.erb
<p>Dies ist eine <strong>Testmail!</strong></p>

/app/views/testmail/email.text.erb
Dies ist eine Test-Email!
```

This is what arrives in my Googlemail-Account:

[image: inbox]

The first email is what it looks like with with the html.erb and text.erb active, the second one with only text.erb.
Ignore the username "root", that's due to a postfix rewrite because of the actual mailer being on another server (emails from the rails server get sent to the mail server which then actually mails them - not my setup ;)

And here's the raw data from the first email:

```
Delivered-To: me@googlemail.com
Received: by 10.101.108.3 with SMTP id k3cs279048anm;
    Wed, 21 Sep 2011 04:24:29 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.204.134.8 with SMTP id h8mr508445bkt.11.1316604268267;
    Wed, 21 Sep 2011 04:24:28 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <inet@our_server>
Received: from our_server (our_server. [100.0.0.0])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTP id i7si2877863bke.151.2011.09.21.04.24.27;
    Wed, 21 Sep 2011 04:24:28 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 100.0.0.0 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of inet@our_server) client-ip=100.0.0.0;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=neutral (google.com: 100.0.0.0 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of inet@our_server) smtp.mail=inet@our_server
Received: from zero (our_server [100.0.0.1])
by our_server (Postfix) with SMTP id 4251724B65
for <me@googlemail.com>; Wed, 21 Sep 2011 13:24:26 +0200 (CEST)
Received: by zero (sSMTP sendmail emulation); Wed, 21 Sep 2011 13:24:26 +0200
From: "root" <inet@our_server>
Date: Wed, 21 Sep 2011 13:24:25 +0200
To: me@googlemail.com
Message-ID: <4e79c96a2ed6b_2ba53f7fe85ced9044023@zero.our_router.mail>
Subject: Willkommen!
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

----==_mimepart_4e79c96a1adc0_2ba53f7fe85ced90437f9
Date: Wed, 21 Sep 2011 13:24:26 +0200
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-ID: <4e79c96a28cbb_2ba53f7fe85ced9043891@zero.our_router.mail>

Dies ist eine Test-Email!

----==_mimepart_4e79c96a1adc0_2ba53f7fe85ced90437f9
Date: Wed, 21 Sep 2011 13:24:26 +0200
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-ID: <4e79c96a2bd8d_2ba53f7fe85ced90439a1@zero.our_router.mail>

<p>Dies ist eine <strong>Testmail!</strong></p>


----==_mimepart_4e79c96a1adc0_2ba53f7fe85ced90437f9--
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, found the answer: The above version of assembling the email does NOT include the boundary neccessary. However,

```
mail(:to => 'whoever@wheree.ver')
```

will work and set the correct boundaries.

Answer (score 3):

Dont know anything about ruby and or rails, but I do know a bit about MIME. Your top level `Content-Type` header should be:

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary="--==_mimepart_4e79c96a1adc0_2ba53f7fe85ced90437f9"
```

Comment: Well, I found this bug report: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/6657  However, I did not find a conclusion to said bug...

Comment: For posterity, the above Lighthouse ticket was migrated to https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/985, closed, and reopened by @Rhywden as https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/3090 which has been closed with the same resolution as Rhywden's solution: don't use the old API, which was removed in Rails 3.2 anyway.